# How to read pandas efficiently, with array of columns names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_a": [1,2,3], "col_b": [5,4,0], "col_c": [9,7,6])
cols = [["col_a", "col_b"], ["col_c", "col_b"], ["col_a", "col_b"]]
```

expected output:

```
[[1,5], [7,4], [3,0]]
```

I know this can be acheived using list comprehension, looking for more efficient way since i have more than million records

Comment: So it would take you about 1s to loop over 1 million records. Do you need to run this repeatedly?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you are trying to do; maybe even show the list comprehension.  I'm **guessing** that you are `zipping` though `cols` and rows of `df`, and using that to select values from successive rows of `df`.

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension that you forgot to supply:

```
In [27]: [row[1][col].to_list() for row, col in zip(df.iterrows(), cols)]
Out[27]: [[1, 5], [7, 4], [3, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this without iterating over the `cols` variable. Try this -

```
[df.loc[i,j].tolist() for i,j in enumerate(cols)]
```

```
[[1, 5], [7, 4], [3, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your labels to the indices then `take_along_axis`

```
d = {c: i for i,c in enumerate(df.columns)}
idx = pd.DataFrame(cols).replace(d).to_numpy()
#array([[0, 1],
#       [2, 1],
#       [0, 1]])

np.take_along_axis(df.to_numpy(), idx, axis=1)
#array([[1, 5],
#       [7, 4],
#       [3, 0]])
```

Comment: Once you have the numerical `idx`, the `take_along_axis` step is quite fast.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks! I wasn’t sure if it was fast or slow, I’ll keep that in mind :)

Comment: thanks a lot...this approach is similar to what i was trying to create.