# Pandas apply row wise access faster

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the example where A and B are measurements and T is a threshold left joined in from another dataframe. T_name represents the column for which that threshold applies. I want to only keep the measurements that are above the thresholds.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,4,4],'B':[9,9,6,6], 'T_name': ['A','B','A','B'], 'T':[2,4,3,5]})
high_values = df[df.apply(lambda row: row[row['T_name']] > row['T'], axis=1)]
```

The output looks like this:

```
  A  B  T_Name T
1 1  9 'B'     4
2 4  6 'A'     3
3 4  6 'B'     5
```

In my dataset I have over 5 million rows and it becomes very slow to do the filtering. The issue has to do with the column access.

```
row[row.T_name]
```

If i break up my code to filter out 'A' and then 'B' then append the 2 datasets, it becomes faster but its less extensible when I'll eventually have more measurement columns.

Is there a way to speed up the filtering?

Note: I've tried swifter but it further slows down the filtering.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but this code doesn't run. Firstly `T_name` and `T` are undefined, but that just seems to be a typo and they should be quoted. After fixing that, I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` since `.T` is short for `.transpose()` and does not access the column. Best practice for accessing a column is with index syntax: `row['T']`. Also, `T_Name` doesn't match `T_name`.

Comment: Related: [How can I select a specific column from each row in a Pandas DataFrame?](/q/24833130/4518341) I would say it's a duplicate but the top answer uses a deprecated method, the second answer isn't very clear, and the third answer uses an overly heavy solution before [the solution that looks best](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels), using `pd.factorize` and NumPy indexing.

Comment: Another solution, but adapting it is a bit of work: [`take_along_axis` posted by ALollz](/a/66643160/4518341) on "How to read pandas efficiently, with array of columns names"

Comment: Related: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](/q/16476924/4518341). TLDR: For performance, prefer vectorization over apply; vectorization may require NumPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) approach from the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) on looking up values by index/column labels, you can generate an array of the test values selected by `T_name`:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,4,4],'B':[9,9,6,6], 'T_name': ['A','B','A','B'], 'T':[2,4,3,5]})

idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['T_name'])
test = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

Another approach (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66643160/9473764)) is to use [`take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to generate the test values:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,4,4],'B':[9,9,6,6], 'T_name': ['A','B','A','B'], 'T':[2,4,3,5]})

d = { c: i for i, c in enumerate(df.columns) }
idx = df[['T_name']].replace(d).to_numpy()
test = np.take_along_axis(df.to_numpy(), idx, axis=1).flat
```

I also tested an approach using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73607470/9473764):

```py
mm = df.melt(id_vars='T_name', value_vars=cols, ignore_index=False)
test = mm[mm['T_name'] == mm['variable']]['value'].loc[df.index]
```

Once `test` has been computed, you can then select rows from the dataframe by comparing those to the `T` values:

```py
out = df[test > df['T']]
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
   A  B T_name  T
1  1  9      B  4
2  4  6      A  3
3  4  6      B  5
```

I ran timing tests on these two approaches and your original code, using `timeit` and this framework (a dataframe with 10 measurements and 1M rows), with the `stmt` code replaced accordingly:

```py
timeit.timeit(setup='''
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, random
M = 10
N = 1000000
data = [random.choices(range(100), k=M) for _ in range(N)]
cols = [f'col{i}' for i in range(M)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df['T_name'] = random.choices(cols, k=N)
df['T'] = random.choices(range(100), k=N)
''', stmt='''
out = df[df.apply(lambda row: row[row['T_name']] > row['T'], axis=1)]
''', number=1)
```

For one iteration, the results were:

```
factorize:         0.05827
take_along_axis:   0.41568
melt:              0.57363
apply:             3.24366
```

As can be seen, the `factorize` code is almost 60x faster than your original code, about 7x faster than the `take_along_axis` code, and about 10x faster than the `melt` code.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df['T_name'])` - You can simplify that to `df[['T_name']]`. BTW, there's also a method `Series.to_frame()`.

Comment: @wjandrea thanks - I carelessly copied the code without thinking about the fact that they were working with more than one column, hence the need for the `pd.DataFrame` call. I've fixed the code.

Comment: @wjandrea fyi I added timing results for the three approaches to my answer. Needless to say the documentation recommended approach is far and away the best.

Comment: What makes the original code so slow? What’s going on under the hood?

Comment: @ShabbirHussain you're calling a function for every row in the database, and in that function you're doing three lookups.

Comment: It took me some time to understand the problem but thanks to @Nick it makes sense. Rather than perform the lookup 1 row at a time, the factorized code transforms the lookup into a numpy array to take advantage of vectorization. In my partiular case, I tested and got a near 60x performance increase.

Comment: @ShabbirHussain that's great to hear. FYI I added another method to the answer, but timings are still nowhere near as good as the factorization approach.